# Call a method at Spring Boot application crash

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, event-handling

For my use case, I wanted to invoke a method `doSomething()` under three scenarios:

1. When my Spring Boot application has started. [Done]
2. When my Spring Boot application is shutting down. [Done]
3. When my Spring Boot application has crashed. [Pending]

Basically, an application crash is a type of application shutdown. But I am looking for a way to differentiate between the two. I want to pass the exception which has caused the application to crash to `doSomething(ex)` as well.

Can I achieve this through `ContextClosedEvent` or is there another way to achieve the functionality?

Comment: first two are fairly trivial, last one, by far no.

Comment: Agreed @Eugene. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am afraid to even know _why_ you think you want that...

Comment: hi @MayankChoudhary, were you able to uniquely application crash without using ContextClosedEvent?

Answer (score 0):

is it ok using @PreDestroy?

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

@Component
public class MyService  {

    @PreDestroy
    public void predestory() {
        System.out.println("--------using predestoy-----");
    }
}
```